# Set a value in percentage in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, percentage

I apologize if some terms I will use, will not be right. I'm not a pro.

I used JavaScript to embed a popup window into a website and I need it to be 50% from the left and 50% from the top. Here is some lines of the code:

```
var exepopuptop = jQuery(window).scrollTop()+50;
var exepopupleft = 50;
```

If I write "`50%`", dw tell me "`there is a syntax error`".

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: You need to write a calculation that outputs a number and use that.

Comment: Try getting window width and height and divide by 2, that will be your new value

Comment: var VerticalcenterPos=$( window ).height()/2;

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem in this way:

```
var exepopupwindow = jQuery(window).height();
var exepopupdiv = jQuery("#exepopup").height();
var exepopuptop = (jQuery(window).scrollTop()+exepopupwindow-exepopupdiv) / 2;

var exepopupww = jQuery(window).width();
var exepopupwww = jQuery("#exepopup").width();
var exepopupleft = (exepopupww-exepopupwww)/2;
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: This is really horribly messy and slow code. I will quickly write you a cleaner snippet as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $window = $(window),
    winHeight = $window.height(),
    winWidth = $window.width(),
    $exepopup = $('#exepopup'),
    exepopupHeight = $exepopup.height(),
    exepopupWidth = $exepopup.width(),
    scrollTop = $window.scrollTop(),
    scrollLeft = $window.scrollLeft(),
    offsetTop = (winHeight / 2) - (exepopupHeight / 2) + scrollTop,
    offsetLeft = (winWidth / 2) - (exepopopWidth / 2) + scrollLeft;

if(offsetTop < 0) { offsetTop = 0; }
if(offsetLeft < 0) { offsetLeft = 0; }

$exepopup
    .css('YOUR CSS PROP', offsetTop)
    .css('YOUR CSS PROP', offsetLeft);
```

So why is this cleaner and faster?

First of all cleaner. It is a common convention to group all of the `var` declarations together so that they form a nice clean statement. Additionally using correct casing for variables known as `camelCase`.

Now why is it faster? Well with the original code the issue was that you were rewrapping the window object in jQuery (which takes time), as well as the exepopup element. This way you hold a reference to those and just take from them as required.